# Oracle exception with ADO.Net

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, ora-06550

When I'm trying to execute the following sql block, I got the following Exception

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
The symbol "" was ignored.
ORA-06550: line 2, column 47:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of t
```

The query:

```
begin
insert into test (a, b) values (:p1, :p2);
commit;
end;
```

Note: I added two parameters (p1, p2) with string values

Answer (score -1):

Remove the trailing **;**